# Android Mockito - Mocking an enum?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, enums, mockito

I'm trying to test a method that returns a list of enum when given list of strings.

this is the enum

```
enum class SupportedFeatures(val id: String) {
    FEATURE_1("feature1"),
    ;

    companion object {
        fun getValueFromId(id: String): SupportedFeatures? {
            values().forEach {
                if (it.id == id) {
                    return it
                }
            }

            return null
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method I'm trying to test

```
@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
fun getFilteredList(from: List<String>): MutableList<SupportedFeatures> {
    val to = mutableListOf<SupportedFeatures>()
    from.forEach {
        val supportedFeature = SupportedFeatures.getValueFromId(it)
        if (supportedFeature != null) {
            to.add(supportedFeature)
        }
    }
    return to
}
```

I can test this pretty easily

```
featuresList.addAll(listOf("feature1", "feature2", "feature3"))
target = mutableListOf(SupportedFeatures.FEATURE_1)
Mockito.`when`(featureSelector.getFilteredList(featuresList)).thenReturn(target)
```

but the problem is when I add more features to the `SupportedFeatures` enum.
If I add `FEATURE_2("feature2")` to the enum, suddenly the test will fail. While it is true that the test should fail, but I want to test the functionality of the method without depending on current business logic.

Is there any way to Mock the `SupportedFeatures` enum in the test class? or am I not separating methods into smaller pieces somehow?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your test specifically trying to evaluate? Whether all expected IDs return an enum member? Incidentally, this particular function seems redundant since you could just use `SupportedFeatures.of("FEATURE_1")` and omit the IDs. But maybe this is a simplified example of what you're actually doing.

Comment: Your 3 lines of code is not a test? There is no assertion.

Comment: Also, you’re not testing `getFilteredList`, you’re mocking it.

Comment: @Tenfour04, I'm getting the list of ids from the server, and I need to make sure the client can handle them. As the server does not know about the name of the enum, I can't do `SupportedFeatures.of("FEATURE_1")`

Comment: Typically, an enum is something you would just use directly in a test since enums don’t normally hold mutable state. You mock things that may not be available or behave consistently for the test, like perhaps a remote server’s response or user input through a UI.